# Marca de página atual errada na paginação do Bootstrap4

Tags: php, paginação, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando usar a paginação do bootstrap4 mas a página ativa está vindo errada. Por exemplo, a primeira página vem como página 2. Meu código está assim:

```
            <nav>
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                  <a href="?id=45&pg=<?php echo $num_paginas-1; ?>" aria-label="Anterior">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <?php 
                for($i=0;$i<$num_paginas;$i++){
                $estilo = "";
                if($pagina == $i)
                    $estilo = "class=\"active\"";
                ?>
                <li <?php echo $estilo; ?> ><a href="?id=45&pg=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i+1; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
                <li>
                  <a href="?id=45&pg=<?php echo $num_paginas+1; ?>" aria-label="Próximo">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi a variável $pagina está sendo capturada via GET como sendo a pagina atual, certo?

Supondo que o get está sendo passada como ?id=45&pg=1, para a pagina 1, nesse caso quando $i for 1 ele vai entrar no if

```
if($pagina == $i)
                    $estilo = "class=\"active\"";
```

e vai colocar o estilo para sendo pagina ativa, porém, na hora de exibir, $i está recebendo +1, logo, $i+1 = 2.

Ou você pode exibir o $i sem adicionar o valor ou contar o 0 como sendo pagina 1.